# Firebase 3: Server authentication in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

In the old Firebase, I used to be able to authenticate in iOS using the server method in which a secret is generated on Firebase website and `signInWithCustomToken` is used to sign in with full admin privilege.

Can this still be done with the new Firebase? I can't seem to find a way to. The same function and secret would return this error:

```
Error Domain=FIRAuthErrorDomain Code=17000 "The custom token format is incorrect..."
```